# How to find non repetitive letter from a given string

Tags: text-processing

I have a string `aaabefhhhhhthkkd` from which I just need to extract non repetitive letters as output, preserving the order.

The string may contain upper case or lower case letters.

**Input:**

```
aaabefhhhhhthkkd
```

**Output:**

```
beftd
```

How this logic need to be defined so that I get the above required output?

I tried to use this command but it only partially worked for me:

```
echo "aaabefhhhhhthkkd" | sed 's/./&\n/g' | uniq
```

**Output of above partially worked command:**

```
a
b
e
f
h
t
h
k
d
```

**Sample String to test:**

```
String 1: aaabefhhhhhthkkd -> Output -> beftd

String 2: AAAbefhhhhhThkkD -> Output -> befTD 

String 3: AAAbefhMThkkD    -> Output -> befMTD
```

Comment: I wish you had included in your examples a combination of upper and lower case instances of a single letter so we could see if you wanted the comparison to be case sensitive or not.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It took so time to implement this but below approach as worked for me as expected and I am finally done !!!

**Tested on below string**

**String 1:** aaabefhhhhhthkkd -> Output -> beftd

**String 2:** AAAbefhhhhhThkkD -> Output -> befTD

**String 3:** AAAbefhMThkkD    -> Output -> befMTD

```
#!/bin/bash

# String passed as an input 
str='AAAbefhMThkkD'

# Taking character count of provided string 
count=$(echo "$str" | tr -cd 'a-z|A-Z' | wc -c)

# Dynamic array created 
dynamic_array=()

# Looping through the for loop 
for (( i=1 ; i<=$((count)) ; i++ ))
{
    c=$(echo "$str" |  cut -c "$i")
    character_count=$(echo "$str" | tr -cd "$c" | wc -c) 
    echo "Character : $c  : $character_count" 

   if [ "$character_count" -eq 1 ]
   then  
        dynamic_array+=("$c")   
   fi           
}

str_array_value="${dynamic_array[*]}" ; echo "Output : ${str_array_value// /}" 

# Input :  aaabefhhhhhthkkd : Output : beftd 
# Input :  AAAbefhhhhhThkkD : Output : befTD
# Input :  AAAbefhMThkkD    : Output : befMTD
```

Code corrected on [https://www.shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/)

Comment: You should copy/paste that into http://shellcheck.net and fix the issues it tells you about. There are other issues too that it won't tell you about because manipulating text just isn't what a shell is designed to do and so it's hard to code it correctly. Manipulating text is what awk was designed to do and shells were designed to call tools like awk to perform such tasks.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. http://shellcheck.net is a web site where you copy/paste your shell script into it and it tells you about the basic problems, that's all. If I were you I'd use that as a learning opportunity for basic shell programming BUT at the end of the day I wouldn't use a shell script with loops like you have for this as it's just the wrong approach so it's not really worth trying to fix ALL of the issues (the ones shellcheck will tell you about and the rest).

Comment: Trying to fix a looping shell script to manipulate text would be like trying to fix your pogo stick to do the 20 mile trip to work. Sure you CAN do it but there are far better alternatives. It's not a coincidence that there are no shell loops in anyone else's answer. If you don't understand something that shellcheck is telling you about after reading the references it provides then post a new question about that.

Answer (score 5):

`uniq` only works on adjacent duplicates - so if you want to use that, you'd need to sort your input first, for example:

```
fold -w1 | sort | uniq -u | paste -sd ''
```

- `fold -w1` does the same as your `sed 's/./&\n/g'` but without introducing an extra spurious newline
- `sort` to make duplicate characters adjacent
- `uniq -u` the `-u` is important to only print singletons
- `paste -sd ''` joins the result back into a single line

Because of the sorting, you will not be able to get your desired output order in all cases ex.

```
$ echo 'AAAbefhMThkkD' | fold -w1 | sort | uniq -u | paste -sd ''
  DMTbef
```

---

If you don't want to roll your own solution, you could always use Perl's `MoreUtils`:

```
$ echo 'AAAbefhMThkkD' |
    perl -MList::MoreUtils=singleton -ne 'print singleton split //'
befMTD
```

Comment: Note that with the GNU implementation of `fold`, that won't work if the input has multi-byte characters. On GNU systems, you may prefer `grep -o .`. Also note that POSIX `paste` requires at least one filename argument (which can be `-` to specify stdin).

Comment: With the `perl` variant, you may want to add a `-Mopen=locale` to work with characters (as per the locale's encoding) instead of bytes.

Answer (score 3):

```c
awk '
{
  n=split($0, a, "")
  for(i=1; i<=n; i++){
    if(gsub(a[i], "") == 1){ printf("%s", a[i]) }
  }
  print ""
}'
```

- `n=split($0, a, "")`: `a[1]` becomes the 1st character of the string, `a[2]` the 2nd, etc. `n` is the total number of characters.
- `for(i=1; i<=n; i++)`: Let's loop over all the array `a`.
- `if(gsub(a[i], "") == 1)`: Delete all `a[i]` characters from the string. If only one character was deleted on the string,

  - `printf("%s", a[i])` print that character.
- `print ""` prints a newline character after all the line has been processed. This is optional if you have a single input line.

Example with condensed one-liner:

```
$ awk '{n=split($0,a,"");for(i=1;i<=n;i++)if(gsub(a[i],"")==1)printf("%s",a[i])}' <<< AAAbefhMThkkD
befMTD
```

Note: Splitting on a null string is not defined by POSIX. However, `gawk` (the GNU Awk), `mawk` and [`original-awk`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/original-awk) all implement the operation as desired.

Comment: Awesome it worked … I was also trying with logic like cut first character , loop in for loop check the character in string - cut character | grep and check the status and add it to an dynamic array

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "original-awk". oawk as in /bin/awk on Solaris? I'd be surprised if it behaved as intended here (not that anyone would care if it did or not, it'd just be an odd thing to mention)

Comment: Np, thanks for providing the link. Sounds like that might be an implementation of "new awk", `nawk`. Can't imagine why they called it "original-awk" if that is the case.

Comment: @EdMorton, that's the one that used to be maintained by Brian Kernighan (the K in awk), (now a community effort (https://github.com/onetrueawk/awk)) so descendant from the original implementation. bwk did take a few features from gawk. You'll see the gawk maintainer is now contributing to that awk.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Oh, I've heard of "one true awk" of course, just never heard of it being called "original awk". Thanks for the info. Too bad there's yet ANOTHER awk name for people to have to know, but at least it's not a different variant from the commonly known set. Yeah, I know Arnold's involved in that too.

Answer (score 3):

With `sed`, you could do something like:

```
sed '
  :1
  /\(.*\(.\).*\)\2/ { # while there is a duplicated char
    s//\2\1/; # move it to the front
    :2
      # remove characters that are the same as the first in a loop:
      s/^\(\(.\).*\)\2/\1/
    t2
    s/^.//
    b1
  }'
```

With the GNU implementation of `sed`, you can shorten it to:

```
sed -E ':1;s/(.*(.).*)\2/\2\1/;T;:2;s/^((.).*)\2/\1/;t2;s/^.//;t1'
```

If you want to do the check for duplicates case insensitively (for `áÁbBcδΔ` to become `c` for instance), you can add the `i` flag to the first 2 `s` commands in the GNU `sed` code above. Note however that it won't work for things like German `ß` vs `SS`.

And that would still not handle [Unicode equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence) and work at character (not grapheme cluster) level, so for instance if you have `aéá` where those accented letters are expressed in their *decomposed* form, not only a U+00E9 `é` would not be considered the same as a U+0065 U+0301 `é`, but that `aéá` expressed as `U+0061 U+0065 U+0301 U+0061 U+0301` would become `e` (U+0065), the only non-duplicated *character* in there, even if those 5 characters actually end up forming 3 distinct grapheme clusters. My first name in its decomposed form would become `St́phan` (with the combining acute accent landing on the `t` when both `e`s are removed).

Using:

```
perl -Mopen=locale -lpe 's/\b{g}\Q$1\E\b{g}//gi while m/(\X)\X*\1/i'
```

here extending [@sitaram's answer](/a/619181) (using `-Mopen=locale` to treat input as characters instead of bytes, `\X` instead of `.` to match a grapheme cluster instead of character, and `\b{g}` for grapheme cluster boundary) would address some of those issues (not breaking down grapheme clusters in the middle, `ß` vs `SS`), but not the unicode equivalence:

```
$ echo $'groß KUSS. Ste\u0301phane, \ue9' |  perl -Mopen=locale -lpe 's/\b{g}\Q$1\E\b{g}//gi while m/(\X)\X*\1/i'
groKU.Stéphane,é
```

(`ß` spotted as duplicate of `SS`, the `e` in `e\u0301` not associated with the standalone `e`, but the two variants of `é` not recognised as the same).

Also note that `ß/SS` would be turned to `/` as `ß` is processed first while `SS/ß` would turned to `/ß` as the `S` is processed first.

It would also turn `ßA/SAS` into `/` as removing the duplicate `A`s would reveal a `SS`, the uppercase version of `ß`. To avoid that, you could change it to:

```
perl -Mopen=locale -lpe 's/\b{g}\Q$1\E\b{g}/\n/gi while m/((?!\n)\X)\X*\1/i; s/\n//g'
```

That is, instead of removing the duplicate grapheme clusters, we change them to *newline* preventing characters on either side to be joined into a sequence of grapheme clusters that could the uppercase or lowercase variant of another grapheme cluster.

Answer (score 3):

Using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ echo 'aaabefhhhhhthkkd' |
    awk '{
        lgth = length()
        for (pos=1; pos<=lgth; pos++) {
            let = substr($0,pos,1)
            if ( gsub(let,"&") == 1 ) {
                printf "%s%s", let, (pos<lgth ? "" : ORS)
            }
        }
    }'
beftd
```

Comment: That is a nice variation, Ed. I think readers would benefit from a explanation from the most hairy parts ;)

Comment: Anything in particular that's not obvious (and not already present/discussed in thousands of scripts all over the internet!)?

Comment: All that is quite clear for both of us, but maybe `gsub(let,"&")` and what's the trick with `(pos<lgth ? "" : ORS)` could be enlightnening for others. (Yeah, surely it is areound the internet, but it can be a helping hand. For example "what does & mean in gsub" does not return me anything relevant.) But that is just a suggestion, of course.

Comment: `gsub(regexp,"&")` is the idiomatic awk way to just count occurrences of strings matching a regexp and the ternary `(i<max ? OFS ? ORS)` is the idiomatic awk way when looping to print a separator between output strings followed by ORS at the end. Both are extremely common, we can't/shouldn't keep explaining the same common, idiomatic code everywhere it's used IMHO>

Comment: When I do https://www.google.com/search?q=awk+what+does+%22%26%22+mean+in+gsub I get a box at the top of the page with big bold letters which says `substitute full match ... 
& means "substitute full match" in awk regexes, including gsub` and a link to read more about it at [awk-gsub-ampersands-and-unexpected-expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43172002/awk-gsub-ampersands-and-unexpected-expansion)

Comment: I guess ddg.gg is still lagging behind with complicated keywords then.

Comment: Would be worth noting that it assumes that like in the OP's case, none of the characters in the input are regexp operators (like `.`, `$`...).

Comment: That's why I named the variable `let` for letter instead of `char` for character.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to repeat all actions inside the loop for each of the 5 `h` (for example), better **remove** all repeated letters just once. Implemented in my answer.

Comment: I'll take your word for it, I don't remember this question at all and don't feel a burning desire to re-learn what it's about!

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `awk` assigning empty string to FS.

From [GNU awk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Field-Splitting-Summary.html#Field-Splitting-Summary):

> FS == ""
>
> Each individual character in the record becomes a separate field. (This is a common extension; it is not specified by the POSIX standard.)

```
echo 'aaabefhhhhhthkkd' | awk -v FS= -v ORS='' '
{for (i=1; i<=NF;i++) if ( gsub($i,"&") == 1 ) print $i;print "\n"}'
beftd
```

Answer (score 1):

Variation on a theme

```
echo 'aaabefhhhhhthkkd' | 
 awk '{while (length()>0) {t=substr($0,1,1); printf (gsub( t ,"")==1)?t:""} print}'

beftd
```

Consume `$0` by replacing the first character with `""` until empty and print when only one replacement occurs.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work fine:

```
$ echo 'aaabefhhhhhthkkd' | perl -pe 's/$1//g while m/(.).*\1/'
beftd
```

Pretty easy to understand even if you don't know perl; it's just regex the way it's used in sed and any other such tools. Even the way while works is same as, say, bash/sh so that should be clear enough also.

I must admit I did not really understand all the solutions offered -- seemed like too much code for such a straightforward problem.  I am guessing I missed something :-(

Also, if you want the *comparison* to be case-insensitive, add an `i` flag to the `m//` and the `s///g`:

```
$ echo 'aaabefhhHhhthkkd' | perl -pe 's/$1//gi while m/(.).*\1/i'
beftd
```

Comment: Like for the other `perl`-based variants, you may want to change `$1` to `\Q$1\E` (to handle characters that happen to be regexp operators) and add `-Mopen=locale` to handle non-ASCII input.

Answer (score 0):

Without awk:

```
string="aaabefhhhhhthkkd" && discard=$(echo $string|fold -w1|sort|uniq -d|tr -d '\n') && echo $string|sed "s/[$discard]//g"
```

Explanation:

```
string="aaabefhhhhhthkkd"
```

sets your string as variable 'string'

```
&&
```

separates the two commands, making sure second part runs after variable assignment.

```
discard=$(echo $string|fold -w1|sort|uniq -d|tr -d '\n')
```

will find all non unique characters in $string and save them in variable $discard. (unroll to characters, sort, identify non-uniques, roll back, save to variable)

```
echo $string|sed "s/[$discard]//g"
```

will remove characters that are non-unique from string

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple Perl one-liner (with a little help from `echo`):

```
echo aaabefhhhhhthkkd | perl -ple 'my %z; for my $c (split q//){$z{$c}++} for my $k (keys %z){$_ =~ s/\Q$k\E//g if $z{$k} > 1}'
```

Explanation:

1. `-p`: wrap a loop around the given program, each input line is in the default variable `$_`, and print each input line after processing
2. `-l`: handle newlines so you don't have to
3. `-e`: run the following as perl code
4. `my %z`: initialise a hash to keep character counts in (for each line)
5. `for my $c (split q//)`: split the default variable, `$_`, into `$c`, looping over each character
6. `$z{$c}++`: increment the count for character `$c`
7. `for my $k (keys %z)`: for each key in `%z`, the count of characters seen
8. `$_ =~ s/$k//g if $z{$k} > 1`: remove all instances of character `$k` if its count is greater than 1

Comment: You'd want to use `s/\Q$k\E//g` to avoid problems with values of `$k` that happen to be regexp operators.

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

From Ed Morton answer, but replacing each character only once (much faster):

```
$ echo 'aaabefhhhhhthkkd' | 
    awk '{
           while ( length() ) {            # process all letters.
               let = substr($0,1,1)        # extract the first letter
               if ( gsub(let,"") == 1 ) {  # remove all letters (and count)
                   printf "%s", let        # if not repeated, print the letter
               }
           }
           printf "%s", ORS                # print "end of record" delimiter.
          }'

beftd
```