# I am trying to find all the even numbers in the array and add the variable A to them then print it out but I am having problems doing so

Tags: bash

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
declare -i A=2
ADD()
{
    declare -a Arr
    count=1
    MAXCOUNT=4
    #declare -a arr
    while [ "$count" -le "$MAXCOUNT" ]; do
            Arr[$count]=$(( RANDOM % 10 + 1 ))
        (( count++ )) || true
    done
    for i in "${Arr[@]}"; do
        if [ $((Arr[i]%2)) -eq 0 ]; then
            A+=$(Arr[i])
    fi
    done
echo "$A"
}
ADD
```

```
./math1804262.sh: line 35: Arr[*]: command not found
./math1804262.sh: line 35: Arr[*]: command not found
no
./math1804262.sh: line 35: Arr[*]: command not found
```

Comment: it will be helpful if you could provide Input and Output example .. have a look at this question just for reference : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/618599/how-to-find-non-repetitive-letter-from-a-given-string

Comment: have look at code 1 and code 2 output is this you needed as an Output

Comment: What is your intention with the line `A+=$(Arr[i])`?

Comment: Your question contains some code and some errors. What is the question?  Note that we have no way of knowing what your intention is with this code, i.e. what you expect it to output.  Also note that "adding A" could mean several things. I also don't quite see the need to keep track of the numbers in an array at all.

Comment: Your question contains some code and some error messages (from different code).

Answer (score 0):

**Code 1 :**

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -i A=2
ADD()
{
     start_value=$1
     end_value=$2
     dynamic_array=()

     for (( i=$start_value ; i<=$end_value ; i++ ))
     {
         rem=$(( $i % 2 )) 
         if [ $rem -eq 0 ]
         then
             #echo "Number : $i print's even number"
             dynamic_array+=("$i") 
         else
            # echo "Not a even number : $i"
        fi

     }

     # Printing all even numbers
     echo ${dynamic_array[@]}

}

ADD 1 7
```

**Output 1:** `2 4 6`

**The code 2 will print the A alternatively , just little bit change made in dynamic array storing**

**Code 2 :**

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -i A=2
ADD()
{
     start_value=$1
     end_value=$2
     dynamic_array=()

 for (( i=$start_value ; i<=$end_value ; i++ ))
 {
     rem=$(( $i % 2 )) 
     if [ $rem -eq 0 ]
     then
         #echo "Number : $i print's even number"
         dynamic_array+=("$i A") 
     else
         echo "Not a even number : $i"
    fi

 }

 # Printing all even numbers
 echo ${dynamic_array[@]}
```

}

ADD 1 7

**Output 2 :**

```
2 A 4 A 6 A
```

Comment: A should be added to the even numbers in the array of random numbers then the values should be printed

Comment: @Wissi It will be easy if you could share the Output as how i displayed after my code what is the output .. just make some changes in question and add Output