# grep multiple words that have space

Tags: command-line, grep

I have logs file that contain date and username something like below

```
Nov 05 14:36:03.752146 server.com  [2020-11-05T14:36:03.752Z] [C 7f7e597fa700] R=6ssssdsdsd 91,CN= user1 drop: UP 10.11.100.100 TO 10.20.20.139 ICMP 8:0:1:23249 SIZE 60
```

how can I grep date which Nov 05 and user1 in the commandline

Thanks

Comment: can you add little bit more log details and even Output how you required for reference  :  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/618599/how-to-find-non-repetitive-letter-from-a-given-string/618611#618611

Comment: and please show us your attempt at solving the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this will help you to get the details  : Run the below command on website : https://rextester.com/l/bash_online_compiler

```
#!/bin/bash

str='Nov 05 14:36:03.752146 server.com [2020-11-05T14:36:03.752Z] [C 7f7e597fa700] R=6ssssdsdsd 91,CN= user1 drop: UP 10.11.100.100 TO 10.20.20.139 ICMP 8:0:1:23249 SIZE 60'
dt=`echo "$str" | cut -f1 -d":"| awk '{print $1 " " $2}'`
echo "Date : $dt"

Usr=`echo "$str" | cut -d',' -f2 | cut -d':' -f1 | awk '{print $1 " " $2}'`
echo $Usr
```

**Output :**

```
Date : Nov 05
CN= user1
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies

I tried this and it gave me the results I wanted
cat file.log | grep Nov 05 | grep -i user1

it might sound ugly but it worked

Comment: If you're happy with one or several of the answers, upvote them.  If one is solving your issue, [accepting it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) would be the best way of saying "Thank You!"  Accepting an answer also indicates to _future_ readers that the answer actually solved the problem.

Comment: In addition to my previous comment, I sincerely doubt that `grep Nov 05` did what you wanted it to do (it would try to read from a file called `05`).